# error: cannot find symbol if (!"ovpn3".equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR))

Tags: android-studio, vpn, openvpn, android-vpn-service

When I create vpn app I am geting this type of error plz someone help me in this

C:\Users\asus\Desktop\WorkBook\UltimateVpn\app\src\main\java\de\blinkt\openvpn\core\OpenVPNService.java:472: error: cannot find symbol
if (!"ovpn3".equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR))
^
symbol:   variable FLAVOR
location: class BuildConfig

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. You are using old ics-vpn library. You can see not exist "BuildConfig.flavor" line anymore.

Libary Url : [ics-openvpn/OpenVPNService.java](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/blob/master/main/src/main/java/de/blinkt/openvpn/core/OpenVPNService.java)